# Does $3 (a+2c) =4 (b+3d)$, with $d>0$, imply $a+c>b+d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $3 (a+2c) =4 (b+3d)$ and $d>0$, then, is the inequality $a+c>b+d$ true? If so,  prove.

Comment: This looks like something copied straight out of a textbook. Show some effort and please show what you have tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: @TobyMak I did try it.  I don't ask questions without trying them before hand.  And sorry to dissapoint,  It was not copied from a textbook

Comment: @user499096: Explaining what you've tried and/or where you got stuck helps potential answerers know how to target a response to your skill level, without wasting time telling you things you might already know. Also, while *you* might not ask questions without trying them beforehand, *very many others* do, so that your question is likely to be summarily down-voted or even closed. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this true then since $d=\frac{3a+6c-4b}{12}$, we need 
$$a+c>b+\frac{3a+6c-4b}{12}$$ or
$$9a+6c-8b>0$$  is true for all reals $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that $3a+6c-4b>0.$

Now, try to find a counterexample.

Take $b=0$ and $c=1$. What is a value of $a$ for counterexample?